# JCheckBox not getting updated

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am not able to get why `null` is appearing. The `checkBox` should have a name assigned to it

```
    imagesToBeImportedCheckBox = new JCheckBox[imagesToBeImported.size()];
    int check_Box_Number=0;
    for(ResourceListObject currentImage : imagesToBeImported){


        imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number] = new JCheckBox(currentImage.getName());

        System.out.println("Main Debugger On");
        System.out.println(currentImage.getName());
        System.out.println(check_Box_Number);
        System.out.println(imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number].getName());

        imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number].setBounds(6, gapping+check_Box_Number*26, 368, 23);

        panel_1.add(imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number]);
        check_Box_Number++;

            }
```

and here's the output

```
Main Debugger On
Migration-image
0
null
Main Debugger On
Imported on: Tuesday, August 20, 2013
1
null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `name` property for the `text` property

```
System.out.println(imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number].getName());
```

Should be

```
System.out.println(imagesToBeImportedCheckBox[check_Box_Number].getText());
```

The `text` property is responsible for determining what is actually displayed on the screen.

It is also what is set when you pass a `String` to `JCheckBox`'s constructor...

```
... = new JCheckBox(currentImage.getName());
```

Will set the `JCheckBox`'s `text` property

Comment: Just missed upvoting it ;)